# In the UK, what is the classification scheme for outbuildings such as sheds and garages?

Tags: garage, shed, planning

As per title, I am building a large wooden shed with large enough doors to be ABLE to get a car in IF required, but not for permanent use a garage.

Under UK planning laws there are slightly differing conditions for these.

So, what would it be considered as? a shed or a garage?!

Comment: The distinction is likely based on square footage, but could be based on anything as Henry jackson points out.

Comment: I doubt its size related, you can buy some massive sheds, FAR bigger than my actual garage.

Comment: What UK planning law distinguishes between garages and sheds? The intertubes only tells me about regulations for small detached structures. If it is possible to put a car in it you'll have to build a floor that can support the weight of the car - that seems to be what the regulations are concerned with.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios Maybe your garage is actually a shed then?

Comment: heh! no my garage is definitely a garage! it is brick, has a GARAGE door and a car in it :-)

Comment: Hmmm... I park my plane in a brick building with a garage door, so surely that type of structure must be a [hangar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangar).

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to check your local codes. In the US, most building code sections begin with a list of definitions, and I assume it's the same elsewhere. If the difference between a shed and a garage is legally significant then they probably define it. It could be based on size, intended use, access to utilities, proximity to other buildings, access to a driveway, construction technique... really anything your local building regulator has decided.

If this is a structure that might need a permit or inspection, you could also just call the relevant office and ask them.